# Sumproduct summing and multiplying 2 matrixes - 4 columns (not criteria)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

I have some columns and i need pr line to add say from O:S and then multiply with corresponding values from column N

So first sum from O:S then multiply with N:N

I could do
=SUMPRODUKT(N:N;O:O) + SUMPRODUKT(N:N;P:P) + SUMPRODUKT(N:N;Q:Q) + SUMPRODUKT(N:N;R:R) + SUMPRODUKT(N:N;S:S)

so I multiply N with each of the columns O to S but im sure there is a better way !
Specialy since it could be from S through QQ  and that would be one boring formula to write

[image: the problem]

Comment: Which version of Excel? The most efficient option would be to add a helper column to add up those columns for you (and possibly even do the multiplication), then use that in the SUMPRODUCT/SUM formula.

Comment: Try: `=SUMPRODUCT(N:N*O:S)`.

Comment: Thank you - Actually I had tried this but got the #Value! error..... this is because I have Headlines in the table with the original formula it ignores thouse... I could modify it to : =SUMPRODUKT(N10:N145*O10:AA145) but as soon as go above 145 I get the #Value! Error again ?

Comment: Maybe some of the values are text so `SUMPRODUCT` will fail. It needs to have only numbers and empty cells. `=""` will not do.

Comment: @MichaelRygaard wrap this part within `IFERROR` --> `N10:N145*O10:AA145` and check what happens, so the formula will be --> `SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(N10:N145*O10:AA145,0))`

Comment: Omg - Line 145 is where my iferror in column N is returning "" ... FRACK - 
Thank you ... now I have =SUMPRODUKT(HVIS.FEJL(N:N*O:Q;0))   or in English =SUMPRODUKT(IFERROR(N:N*O:Q;0))  - AND IT WORKD !

Comment: @MichaelRygaard Sir, glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SUMPRODUCT: The Multiplier of Arrays

- As expected, it's as easy as:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT(N:N*O:S)
  ```
- Here's a small visual study I 'conducted':

[image]

Comment: Thank you - Actually I had tried this but got the #Value! error.....  this is because I have Headlines in the table with the original formula it ignores thouse... I could modify it to : =SUMPRODUKT(N10:N145*O10:AA145)   but as soon as go above 145  I get the #Value!   Error again ?

Comment: just need the addition IFERROR  - then it works...

Answer (score 2):

```
=SUMPRODUKT(HVIS.FEJL(N:N*O:Q;0))  

' or in English

=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(N:N*O:Q,0))
```

Thank you @VBasic2008 and @mayukh-bhattacharya